# Sanity/React app: Access to XMLHTTPREQUEST... 'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present'

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest

I keep getting this error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://2bd1m4v5.api.sanity.io/v1/data/query/production?query=*%5B_type%3D%3D%22website_images%22%5D%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alt%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20aboutImage%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20asset-%3E%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_id%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Also this: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED`

I'm using react app on my frontend, and sanity for my backend. I'm entirely new to this so I was following some tutorials, but they're pretty outdated and haven't been able to find anything more recent. I've been looking at some other stackoverflow questions who had the same issue, but most seem to include some kind of php function for getting the xml http- none of my tutorials included that? The errors keep referencing my about.js, the file I'm currently trying to fetch data from. How do I resolve this? I'm guessing that I'm missing something that the tutorials didn't mention? I've been stuck on this for a week, I'm desperate for help.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './about.css'
import sanityClient from "../client";
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url'
   
const builder = imageUrlBuilder(sanityClient)

    const urlFor = (source) => {
    return builder.image(source)
    }

export default function About() {   

    const [aboutData, setAbout] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        sanityClient.fetch(
            `*[_type=="website_images"]{
                alt,
                aboutImage{
                    asset->{
                        _id,
                        url
                    }
                }
            }`)
            .then((data) => setAbout(data))
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }, [] );

    return (
        <main className="main-about">
            <div className="about-body">
                <div className="about-title">
                    <div className="title-line-left"></div>
                    <h2>about</h2>
                    <div className="title-line-right"></div>
                </div>
                <div className="about-text">
                    <p className="pronouns">(they/them)</p>
                    <p>The Japanese city and the Prefecture of Hiroshima may have been devastated by the atomic bomb over 76 years ago, but today, this site of the destruction is one of the top tourist destinations in the entire country. Statistics released by the nation's tourist agency revealed that around 363,000 visitors went to the metropolis during 2012, with Americans making up the vast majority of that figure, followed by Australians and Chinese.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {aboutData && aboutData.map((website_images, index) => (
            <figure className="photo-position">
                    {/* <img src="{website_images.aboutImage.asset.url}" alt="{website_images.alt}" className="about-photo"></img> */}
                    <img src={urlFor(aboutData.about).url()} alt={aboutData.alt} className="about-photo"/>
            </figure>
            ))}
        </main>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite it saying http:// here, it actually said https://localhost:3000 in my API CORS origin in Sanity, so just needed to change it to http://localhost:3000 instead